# Does Ruby Version Manager interfere with the system scripts on Dream Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux

Since Dream Linux has built in support for Ruby, I'm assuming it will work well as a Rails development environment, but I'm wondering if Ruby Version Manager will interfere with the system version of Ruby.

Generally, when I use RVM, I disable/ignore the system version.  How will the Dream Linux OS system scripts that are written in Ruby react to the presence of RVM?  If I can't use RVM on Dream Linux, how easy is it to upgrade to newer versions of Ruby, without frazzling the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM should not interfere with your system Ruby, because RVM depends on modifying your (the current user's) path.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview1/bin/ruby
$ rvm 1.9.1
$ which ruby
/Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
$ rvm system
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

By default, then, Dream Linux *should* automatically go to `/usr/bin/ruby` (or equivalent).  Since your RVM Ruby's are "hidden" in your home directory, Dream Linux shouldn't even know they exist unless you specifically go out of your way to point it towards them.

Comment: thanks, it's reassuring.  I think that answers my question then.  I'll make the switch tonight and update the question with my findings if there any.